# php combine array key values?

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm looking to combine two arrays into one array, but I would like to keep the key values the same and accumulate their values into one.

Using PHP I'm looking for something like this:

```
//inputs
array(
   cat => 4,
   dog => 3,
   bug => 6

);

array(
   cat => 2,
   dog => 5,
   bug => 9,
   ant => 3

);


//output
array(
   cat => 6,
   dog => 8,
   bug => 15,
   ant => 3

);
```

Comment: you need to use loop for that

Answer (score 1):

You could add the arrays by adding each of the indexes: (this assumes that your first array is array1 and so on)

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i ++) {
    $array3[i] = $array1[i] + $array2[i];
}
?>
```

Assuming each of your arrays has 4 variables in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function func(&$value, $key) {
    $value = (isset($value[1]) ? $value[0] + $value[1] : $value[0]);
}

$new_array = array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2);
array_walk($new_array, 'func');
print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$final_array = array ();

// u can iterate and get the name of the key while doing so, like so
// add the first array
foreach ($array1 as $prop=>$val)
{
    $final_array[$prop]+=$val;
}


//add the second array
foreach ($array2 as $prop=>$val)
{
    $final_array[$prop]+=$val;
}

//result is in final_array

//or more efficiently, just add the second to the first
foreach ($array2 as $prop=>$val)
{
    $array1[$prop]+=$val;
}
```